# angularjs-disqus want to show topics comments count in top page

Tags: angularjs, disqus

I am using angularjs and embedded disqus to successfully. however, I want to display the comment count of each topic comments on the top page or index page where topics are listed. like this

index/top page is listed like this

```
            <tr ng-repeat="news_item in main_index_news track by $index">
                <td class="headline_link">
                    <a href="{{ decodeURL(news_item.url) }}"
                       ng-click="ga_event(news_item)">{{ news_item.title }}</a>
                    <table class="post_info">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>created_at: {{ timeToLocal(news_item.time) | date:"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm" }}</td>
                                <td>rate: {{ news_item.rate }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a ng-href="/news/{{ news_item._id }}#disqus_thread" 
                                        title="{{ news_item.title }}">
                                        discuss
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I have followed [this](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-adding-comment-count-links-to-your-home-page) tutorial, but I cant get it right.

I hope I am making a sense, because I am clueless, and its my first time to use `disqus` and I am really amazed by it.